# How to Loop through payload in python to send data to a server

Tags: python, pandas, payload

I have a csv file and I want to send each value of the each row in database using payload. What I have tried is

```html
for index,row in df.iterrows():
var1=row['A']
for index,row in df.iterrows():
var2=row['B']
for index,row in df.iterrows():
var3=row['c']
url="http://10.67.46.8/api/data/create.php"
payload='{"A":"'+str(var1)+'","B":"'+str(var2)+'","C":"'+str(var3)+'"}'
headers={
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token':"ca64cf56-19e8-4e6c-85a7-1741355ced79"
}
response=request.request("POST",url,data=payload,headers,headers)
print(response.text)
```

I want to get each and every value of var1, var2, var3 to pass through payload, but only last value of each variable is passed by the payload. what should I do to make loop on payload. so that it can pass each value to database.

Comment: Could you include some of your data, and what your result should look like? This will be helpful.

Comment: I have a table name data in which I have three columns A, B ,C i want to store each value of columns that i am getting from iterrows in that table using payload.